# Random number generator getting errors with ++

Tags: java

I'm making random number generator, then having the user guess the number. The computer will then tell the user if the number is correct and how far the guess was from the avtual number. When I compile:

```
public static void guessNumber()
{
    //Asks for guess of the number. Prints whether the guess is above or below randomNumber.
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    numberOfTries = 0;
    while(userGuess != randomNumber){
        System.out.println("Guess the number ");
        int userGuess = reader.nextInt();
        if (userGuess == randomNumber) {
            int numberOfGuesses++;
            System.out.println("Correct! It took you " + numberOfTries + " tries to find my numnber");
        } else {
            int distanceFromNumber = Math.abs(randomNumber - userGuess);
            int numberOfGuesses++;
            System.out.println("Incorrect! The number that you guessed is " + distanceFromNumber + "numbers away from my number ");
       }
   }
```

I get this error:

```
C:\!!VHSJava\Projects\random.java:47: error: ';' expected
     int numberOfGuesses++;
                        ^
C:\!!VHSJava\Projects\random.java:51: error: ';' expected
     int numberOfGuesses++;
                        ^
```

I've tried changing it to numberOfGuesses += 1, but that got the same error.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about incrementing a variable while declaring it.

Comment: @devnull I don't see how that makes it off-topic. Not saying it is a great question or shows a ton of research effort. It just seems novice, not off-topic, right?

Comment: @Gray What about the __minimal understanding__ reason?

Comment: @devnull I dunno. Clearly there is a misunderstanding, but then every *XY Problem* question would be off-topic, right? They showed attempted solutions, the code, and the error message for why it didn't work. I feel like it is on-topic, just trivial to solve. Thanks for any explanation; I'm not trying to be argumentative, I just want to make sure I better understand what is on/off topic... cause I flag a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
int numberOfGuesses++;
```

You cannot increment value while declaring.

define your variable before like

```
 int numberOfGuesses =0
```

and increment later

```
numberOfGuesses++
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable first and then use it. Both can't be done together in the same statement, because the `numberOfGuesses` does not even have a value for you to increment it yet.

```
int numberOfGuesses = 0; // declare it before the if
...
numberOfGuesses++; // use it in the if
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the integer in a higher level of scope, then increment it:

```
int numberOfGuesses = 0;

//...
    numberOfGuesses++;
```